# Morphisms are determined by stalks

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Suppose $h_1$ and $h_2$ are morphisms from a presheaf of sets $F$ to a sheaf of sets $G$ that induce the same map on each stalk. I'd like to show that $h_1=h_2$.

Consider the following diagram:
$$\begin{array}
A F(U) & {\longrightarrow} & G(U) \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\prod_{p\in U}F_p & {\longrightarrow} & \prod_{p\in U}G_p  
\end{array}
$$ where the vertical maps are given by the natural map to the stalks at each $p\in U$, the top map is either $h_1(U)$ or $h_2(U)$ and the bottom map is the induced map on stalks at each $p$. We have that $s\in F(U)$ maps down to $\prod_{p\in U}s_p$, which then maps to the right to $\prod_{p\in U}h_{1,p}(s_p)=\prod_{p\in U}h_{2,p}(s_p)$ (where the equality holds by assumption).

Now, if the diagram commutes, then we would have the result, since the map from $G(U)$ to $\prod_{p\in U}G_p$ is injective. My question, though, is why does the square commute?

Comment: Suppose you forget about the products. Do you understand why your diagram commutes now?

Comment: @KReiser Of course! Sometimes I get lost in the notation. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. If that's resolved your issue, please consider writing an answer to your own question in order to benefit others who might have this issue in the future.